# Что конкретно нужно знать Android-разработчику?

Tags: java, android

Хочу стать Android-разработчиком. Что нужно знать для этого? Сейчас учу java SE. Куда двигатся после завершения курса? Нужен ли java FX и java EE?

Comment: Увы, такие вопросы не соответствуют манифесту сообщества. Здесь спрашивают про конкретные проблемы

Comment: Мне удалить вопрос?

Comment: Я не знаю. Это ваше право

Comment: Можете переформулировать "Нужно ли знать java FX и java EE разработчику Android?" :)

Comment: Ну при изучении java видел такие курсы думал нужны будут. Поэтому я здесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java SE достаточно как базы для начала. Можете сразу переходить к изучению платформы Android.

- Android Studio
- базовая архитектура приложений
- Android API
- Gradle

Вот отсюда и по порядку: https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

После того как освоитесь, можете глянуть в Kotlin.

Comment: А что на счет Spring? Он нужен?

Comment: Только если http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/ и то после изучения азов Android.

Comment: Просто слышал фреймворк очень сильно помогает в разработке, меньше времени уходит на написания кода.

Comment: @Olexandr прежде чем юзать фреймворки - научитась писать код, а то 90% таких вот юзеров библиотек, понятия не имеющих как оно внутри работает и почему именно так а не иначе.